# Azure API Management - Import Open API from Internal Service

Tags: azure-api-management

we have our APIM instance deployed as external but with access to our backend services deployed in a VNET. These services are accessible from only from within that VNET.

Now, we are trying to add a new API using the OpenAPI specification using the URL of the Swagger file (like: http://internalIP/swagger/v1/swagger.json). We first get a notification saying that the URL of the swaggger file should be publicly available and on the popup window it says: Please specify valid OpenAPI specification file.

We actually generated the swagger file locally and uploaded it to the specification by selecting the file and it worked. So the json is valid. It does not work when we enter the URL for the file which, as I said, it is not publicly available.

Can we add OpenAPI specs using an internal URL?

Thanks a lot and regards,

P

Comment: Any process now?

Comment: I am experiencing this same behavior. The feedback link found in the first answer is a 404.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we add OpenAPI specs using an internal URL?

It seems that it's hard to import OpenApi from internal URL.

Here is a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/34599748-api-management-import-openapi-from-internal-url) that you could vote it up to promote the function implementation.

Comment: Any news on this? We run into the same problem. Your link is dead

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue and as far as I understand it correctly the request to fetch the open api spec file is done through an (shared/public) azure service which has a different ip address than your api management service.

**Background**

In our case we had the files hosted on a blob storage (with anonymous access) and we wanted to restrict access to this storage account to the virtual network where the api management service was in. As mentioned above this didn't work.

**How we debugged the issue**

We found out in the logs of our storage account that the requests where made from a different ip address. To do this we did the following:

1. We navigated to the storage account
2. In the left menu click on logs in the monitoring section
3. We chose the show anonymous request query
4. We added the column `CallerIpAddress` to the query columns
5. We expended one of our requests and noticed that the ip is totally different.

**Possible workaround**

Add the azure service ip to your white listing of the storage account. This is a risk though, but if the files are not that sensitive, it could be an option.